# Method of Adding CSS from Parent Folder

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors

Peace be upon you all!
I would like to import css from the "src" folder to the "Register.js" file which is located in the "components" folder that is child folder of the "src" folder.

I tried it this way. However, it did not work.
import "../components/index.css";

Answer (score 0):

If your Register.js position

> src > components > Register.js

and you want to access css files on

> src > index.css

then just use:

```
"../index.css"
```